# nternal : Failed to perform step 1 in Navigate Stage 'XXXX' on page 'XXXX' - Not Connected

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am getting "Not Connected" issue while executing a blue prism object. Currently, I'm working for browser application and I have given browser URL and window title in application modeler. 
  If I launch the application by navigation stage it's working fine but I'm expecting like already running browser we need to attach and has to do some automation operations on it.

We tried with navigation stage with actions attach/Active application, getting issue "Not connected".

Can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: Can you provide the URL and title of the page? These might be session based e.g. they change each time you re-launch the website. In this case you'll need to use wildcards in your application modeler's actions.

Answer (score 2):

Blue Prism best practice is to call “Attach” page at the beginning of each action to make sure that BP is connected to the application. This page should look like this:

1. Start
2. Read stage – to check connection status (it will return Flag with connection status)
3. Decision stage – connection flag
4. If connected – go to End
5. If not connected – Navigation stage – Attach

You also need to provide proper input parameters for Attach action, for Browser automation (Internet Explorer) you need to provide at least process name: “iexplore” & child index: 0 (it depends on your TabProcGrowth registry settings).

Blue Prism also recommends to start browser apps using Utility – Environment VBO & Start Process action. There are 2 inputs: Application – Path to internet explorer exe file & Arguments – webpage address. 
If you want to learn more about Browser Automations in Blue Prism I recommend you to familiarize with Blue Prism Guides available on Blue Prism Portal - https://portal.blueprism.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Attach bookmark created? When you are working with object you are creating bookmarks resposible for different things in your obcject(login, start etc) you need to create Attach bookmark.

I never had any problems with attaching to app, except mainframe app.

Copy your Navigate step from Launch bookmark, then create new one(call it attach) and paste that Navigate step. Then Edit it, Chane from launch to attach and in Properties you need to fill "Window Title" and "Process Title". Window title, you have it at the top window bar. Process title, youll find it in Windows Task Menager - Processes.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure exactly sure if this is your problem but let me try as my issue is close to your issue.

I had encountered this: **There is no current stage**

[image]

So what I did was to trigger the reset button in the upper left corner of the Process Studio. Screenshot below.

[image]

Then it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the launched instance of the application is different from the one BP is searching for. To solve this issue close the current instance of the app and Launch it from the Application Modeller.